# Probablity Function / Conditional Probablity

Tags: probability

A discrete integer-valued random variable has the following probability function: $P(X=n) = a_n - a_{n+1}$ where the $a_n$'s are numbers which satisfy the following conditions:

1. $a_0 = 1$
2. $a_0 > a_1 >a_2 >\dots >a_k > a_{k+1} > \dots > 0$

Find $P(X \leq 5 | X > 1)$

What am I supposed to do here? Am I summing up $P(5) + P(4) + ... + P(1)$ and then dividing by $1- P(0) - P(1)$?

Answer (score 1):

It's 
\begin{equation}
\frac{P(x \leq 5 \cap X > 1)}{P(X > 1)} = \frac{P(X=5) + P(X=4) + \cdots + P(X=2)}{ 1 - P(X \leq 1)}
\end{equation}
So you almost got it, except remove $P(X=1)$ for the numerator

Comment: Try to use MathJax to write your answer.

Comment: @Element118 still learning, will edit my answer once I'm familiar with it.